# How can I transform an image so that projected image is same as original

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, camera-calibration

Problem statement: An image A is projected through a projector, goes through a microscope and the projected image is captured via a camera through the same microscope as image B. Due to the optical elements, the B is rotated, sheared and distorted with respect to A. Now, I need to transform A into A' before projection such that B is as close to A as possible.

Initial approach: I took a checkerboard pattern and rotated it at various angles (36, 72, 108, ... 324 degrees) and projected to get a series of A images and B images. I used OpenCV's CalibrateCamera2, InitUndistortMap and Remap functions to convert B into B'. But B' is nowhere near A and rather similar to B (especially there is a significant amount of rotation and shearing that is not getting corrected).

The code (in Python) is below. I am not sure if I am doing something stupid. Any ideas for the correct approach?

```
import pylab
import os
import cv
import cv2
import numpy

# angles - the angles at which the picture was rotated 
angles = [0, 36, 72, 108, 144, 180, 216, 252, 288, 324]
# orig_files - list of original picture files used for projection
orig_files =  ['../calibration/checkerboard/orig_%d.png' % (angle) for angle in angles]
# img_files - projected image captured by camera
img_files = ['../calibration/checkerboard/imag_%d.bmp' % (angle) for angle in angles]
# Load the images 
images = [cv.LoadImage(filename) for filename in img_files]
orig_images = [cv.LoadImage(filename) for filename in orig_files]

# Convert to grayscale
gray_images = [cv.CreateImage((src.height, src.width), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) for src in images]
for ii in range(len(images)):
    cv.CvtColor(images[ii], gray_images[ii], cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
gray_orig = [cv.CreateImage((src.height, src.width), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) for src in orig_images]
for ii in range(len(orig_images)):
    cv.CvtColor(orig_images[ii], gray_orig[ii], cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)

# The number of ranks and files in the chessboard. OpenCV considers
# the height and width of the chessboard to be one less than these,
# respectively.
rank_count = 11
file_count = 10

# Try to detect the corners of the chessboard. For each image,
# FindChessboardCorners returns (found, corner_points). found is True
# even if it managed to detect only a subset of the actual corners.
img_corners = [cv.FindChessboardCorners(img, (rank_count-1, file_count-1)) for img in gray_images]
orig_corners = [cv.FindChessboardCorners(img, (rank_count-1,file_count-1)) for img in gray_orig]

# The total number of corners will be (rank_count-1)x(file_count-1),
# but if some parts of the image are too blurred/distorted,
# FindChessboardCorners detects only a subset of the corners. In that
# case, DrawChessboardCorners will raise a TypeError.
orig_corner_success = []
ii = 0
for (found, corners) in orig_corners:
    if found and (len(corners) == (rank_count - 1) * (file_count - 1)):
        orig_corner_success.append(ii)
    else:
        print orig_files[ii], ': could not find correct corners: ', len(corners)
    ii += 1
ii = 0
img_corner_success = []
for (found, corners) in img_corners:
    if found and (len(corners) == (rank_count-1) * (file_count-1)) and (ii in orig_corner_success):
        img_corner_success.append(ii)
    else:
        print img_files[ii], ': Number of corners detected is wrong:', len(corners)
    ii += 1

# Here we compile all the corner coordinates into single arrays    
image_points = []
obj_points = []
for ii in img_corner_success:
    obj_points.extend(orig_corners[ii][1])
    image_points.extend(img_corners[ii][2])        
image_points = cv.fromarray(numpy.array(image_points, dtype='float32'))
obj_points = numpy.hstack((numpy.array(obj_points, dtype='float32'), numpy.zeros((len(obj_points), 1), dtype='float32')))
obj_points = cv.fromarray(numpy.array(obj_points, order='C'))

point_counts = numpy.ones((len(img_corner_success), 1), dtype='int32') * ((rank_count-1) * (file_count-1))
point_counts = cv.fromarray(point_counts)
# Create the output parameters
cam_mat = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
cv.Set2D(cam_mat, 0, 0, 1.0)
cv.Set2D(cam_mat, 1, 1, 1.0)
dist_mat = cv.CreateMat(5, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)
rot_vecs = cv.CreateMat(len(img_corner_success), 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
tran_vecs = cv.CreateMat(len(img_corner_success), 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
# Do the camera calibration
x = cv.CalibrateCamera2(obj_points, image_points, point_counts, cv.GetSize(gray_images[0]), cam_mat, dist_mat, rot_vecs, tran_vecs)
# Create the undistortion map
xmap = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(images[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
ymap = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(images[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
cv.InitUndistortMap(cam_mat, dist_mat, xmap, ymap)
# Now undistort all the images and same them
ii = 0
for tmp in images:
    print img_files[ii]
    image = cv.GetImage(tmp)
    t = cv.CloneImage(image)
    cv.Remap(t, image, xmap, ymap, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR + cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cv.ScalarAll(0))
    corrected_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(img_files[ii]), 'corrected_%s' % (os.path.basename(img_files[ii])))
    cv.SaveImage(corrected_file, image)
    print 'Saved corrected image to', corrected_file
    ii += 1
```

Here are the images - A, B and B' Actually I don't think the Remap is really doing anything!

[image: A. Original Image]
[image: B. Captured Image]
[image: B'. Undistorted Image]

Comment: Do you know the entire optical setup? If you do you could write the matrix equation of the projection and calculate the inverse on the resulting image. This goes along [these lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis).

Comment: posting a sample image would be more illustrative. as in how close is your B to B'.

Comment: @Bort - no it is not possible to know the entire setup: the microscope's focus can be changed everytime.

Comment: @AruniRC - I just uploaded three images when the original is at 144 degree rotation.

Comment: Beaking it down to the underlying mathematical problem: you like to find a function $f:R^(nxn)->R^(nxn)$ that f(A) = A' such that the underlying setup function O(A') = B. In other words the inverse of O would do it. You might want to define a model for O before proceeding. E.g. f shell be linear and of type M*A+C = A' as a matrix equation, where M is known up to a certain set of parameters describing the sheer and rotation.

Comment: Together with the images you could do a maximum likelihood estimate of the model parameters.

Comment: @Bort that looks like an affine transform. I think I've got the idea: first use camera calibration and undistort to get rid of lens distortions,and then try mapping the corner points from original to captured image using affine transform and then do an inverse on newly captured images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved finally. There were several issues:

1. The original images were not of the same size. Nor were the captured images. Hince, the affine transform from one pair was not applicable to the other. I resized them all to the same size.
2. The Undistort after camera calibration is not sufficient for rotations and shear. The appropriate thing to do is affine transform. And it is better to take three corners of the chessboard as the points for computing the transformation matrix (less relative error).

Here is my working code (I am transforming the original images and saving them to show that the computed transformation matrix in deed maps the original to the captured image):

```
import pylab
import os
import cv
import cv2
import numpy

global_object_points = None
global_image_points = None
global_captured_corners = None
global_original_corners = None
global_success_index = None

global_font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, 1.0)

def get_camera_calibration_data(original_image_list, captured_image_list, board_width, board_height):
    """Get the map for undistorting projected images by using a list of original chessboard images and the list of images that were captured by camera.

    original_image_list - list containing the original images (loaded as OpenCV image).

    captured_image_list - list containing the captured images.

    board_width - width of the chessboard (number of files - 1)

    board_height - height of the chessboard (number of ranks - 1)

    """
    global global_object_points
    global global_image_points
    global global_captured_corners
    global global_original_corners
    global global_success_index
    print 'get_undistort_map'
    corner_count = board_width * board_height
    # Try to detect the corners of the chessboard. For each image,
    # FindChessboardCorners returns (found, corner_points). found is
    # True even if it managed to detect only a subset of the actual
    # corners.  NOTE: according to
    # http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/cpp/calib3d/findChessboardCorners,
    # no need for FindCornerSubPix after FindChessBoardCorners
    captured_corners = [cv.FindChessboardCorners(img, (board_width, board_height)) for img in captured_image_list]
    original_corners = [cv.FindChessboardCorners(img, (board_width, board_height)) for img in original_image_list]
    success_captured = [index for index in range(len(captured_image_list))
                        if captured_corners[index][0] and len(captured_corners[index][1]) == corner_count]
    success_original = [index for index in range(len(original_image_list))
                        if original_corners[index][0] and len(original_corners[index][2]) == corner_count]
    success_index = [index for index in success_captured if (len(captured_corners[index][3]) == corner_count) and (index in success_original)]
    global_success_index = success_index
    print global_success_index
    print 'Successfully found corners in image #s.', success_index
    cv.NamedWindow('Image', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    for index in success_index:
        copy = cv.CloneImage(original_image_list[index])
        cv.DrawChessboardCorners(copy, (board_width, board_height), original_corners[index][4], corner_count)
        cv.ShowImage('Image', copy)
        a = cv.WaitKey(0)
        copy = cv.CloneImage(captured_image_list[index])
        cv.DrawChessboardCorners(copy, (board_width, board_height), captured_corners[index][5], corner_count)
        cv.ShowImage('Image', copy)
        a = cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyWindow('Image')
    if not success_index:
        return
    global_captured_corners = [captured_corners[index][6] for index in success_index]
    global_original_corners = [original_corners[index][7] for index in success_index]
    object_points = cv.CreateMat(len(success_index) * (corner_count), 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
    image_points = cv.CreateMat(len(success_index) * (corner_count), 2, cv.CV_32FC1)
    global_object_points = object_points
    global_image_points = image_points
    point_counts = cv.CreateMat(len(success_index), 1, cv.CV_32SC1)
    for ii in range(len(success_index)):        
        for jj in range(corner_count):
            cv.Set2D(object_points, ii * corner_count + jj, 0, float(jj/board_width))
            cv.Set2D(object_points, ii * corner_count + jj, 1, float(jj%board_width))
            cv.Set2D(object_points, ii * corner_count + jj, 2, float(0.0))
            cv.Set2D(image_points, ii * corner_count + jj, 0, captured_corners[success_index[ii]][8][jj][0])
            cv.Set2D(image_points, ii * corner_count + jj, 1, captured_corners[success_index[ii]][9][jj][10])
        cv.Set1D(point_counts, ii, corner_count)
    # Create the output parameters    
    camera_intrinsic_mat = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
    cv.Set2D(camera_intrinsic_mat, 0, 0, 1.0)
    cv.Set2D(camera_intrinsic_mat, 1, 1, 1.0)
    distortion_mat = cv.CreateMat(5, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)
    rotation_vecs = cv.CreateMat(len(success_index), 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
    translation_vecs = cv.CreateMat(len(success_index), 3, cv.CV_32FC1)
    print 'Before camera clibration'
    # Do the camera calibration
    cv.CalibrateCamera2(object_points, image_points, point_counts, cv.GetSize(original_image_list[0]), camera_intrinsic_mat, distortion_mat, rotation_vecs, translation_vecs)
    return (camera_intrinsic_mat, distortion_mat, rotation_vecs, translation_vecs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # angles - the angles at which the picture was rotated 
    angles = [0, 36, 72, 108, 144, 180, 216, 252, 288, 324]
    # orig_files - list of original picture files used for projection
    orig_files =  ['../calibration/checkerboard/o_orig_%d.png' % (angle) for angle in angles]
    # img_files - projected image captured by camera
    img_files = ['../calibration/checkerboard/captured_imag_%d.bmp' % (angle) for angle in angles]

    # orig_files = ['o%d.png' % (angle) for angle in range(10, 40, 10)]
    # img_files = ['d%d.png' % (angle) for angle in range(10, 40, 10)]
    # Load the images
    print 'Loading images'
    captured_images = [cv.LoadImage(filename) for filename in img_files]
    orig_images = [cv.LoadImage(filename) for filename in orig_files]
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray_images = [cv.CreateImage((src.height, src.width), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) for src in captured_images]
    for ii in range(len(captured_images)):
        cv.CvtColor(captured_images[ii], gray_images[ii], cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
        cv.ShowImage('win', gray_images[ii])
        cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyWindow('win')
    gray_orig = [cv.CreateImage((src.height, src.width), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) for src in orig_images]
    for ii in range(len(orig_images)):
        cv.CvtColor(orig_images[ii], gray_orig[ii], cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)

    # The number of ranks and files in the chessboard. OpenCV considers
    # the height and width of the chessboard to be one less than these,
    # respectively.
    rank_count = 10
    file_count = 11
    camera_intrinsic_mat, distortion_mat, rotation_vecs, translation_vecs, = get_camera_calibration_data(gray_orig, gray_images, file_count-1, rank_count-1)
    xmap = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(captured_images[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    ymap = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(captured_images[0]), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    cv.InitUndistortMap(camera_intrinsic_mat, distortion_mat, xmap, ymap)
    # homography = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_32F)
    map_matrix = cv.CreateMat(2, 3, cv.CV_32F)
    source_points = (global_original_corners[0][0], global_original_corners[0][file_count-2], global_original_corners[0][(rank_count-1) * (file_count-1) -1])
    image_points = (global_captured_corners[0][0], global_captured_corners[0][file_count-2], global_captured_corners[0][(rank_count-1) * (file_count-1) -1])
    # cv.GetPerspectiveTransform(source, target, homography)
    cv.GetAffineTransform(source_points, image_points, map_matrix)
    ii = 0
    cv.NamedWindow('OriginaImage', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv.NamedWindow('CapturedImage', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv.NamedWindow('FixedImage', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    for image in gray_images:
        # The affine transform should be ideally calculated once
        # outside this loop, but as the transform looks different for
        # each image, I'll just calculate it independently to see the
        # applicability
        try:
            # Try to find ii in the list of successful corner
            # detection indices and if found, use the corners for
            # computing the affine transformation matrix. This is only
            # required when the optics changes between two
            # projections, which should not happend.
            jj = global_success_index.index(ii)
            source_points = [global_original_corners[jj][0], global_original_corners[jj][rank_count-1], global_original_corners[jj][-1]]
            image_points = [global_captured_corners[jj][0], global_captured_corners[jj][rank_count-1], global_captured_corners[jj][-1]]
            cv.GetAffineTransform(source_points, image_points, map_matrix)
            print '---------------------------------------------------------------------'
            print orig_files[ii], '<-->', img_files[ii]
            print '---------------------------------------------------------------------'
            for kk in range(len(source_points)):
                print source_points[kk]
                print image_points[kk]
        except ValueError:
            # otherwise use the last used transformation matrix
            pass

        orig = cv.CloneImage(orig_images[ii])        
        cv.PutText(orig, '%s: original' % (os.path.basename(orig_files[ii])), (100, 100), global_font, 0.0)
        cv.ShowImage('OriginalImage', orig)
        target = cv.CloneImage(image)
        target.origin = image.origin
        cv.SetZero(target)
        cv.Remap(image, target, xmap, ymap, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR + cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cv.ScalarAll(0))
        cv.PutText(target, '%s: remapped' % (os.path.basename(img_files[ii])), (100, 100), global_font, 0.0)
        cv.ShowImage('CapturedImage', target)
        target = cv.CloneImage(orig_images[ii])
        cv.SetZero(target)
        cv.WarpAffine(orig_images[ii], target, map_matrix, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR | cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
        corrected_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(img_files[ii]), 'corrected_%s' % (os.path.basename(img_files[ii])))
        cv.SaveImage(corrected_file, target)
        print 'Saved corrected image to', corrected_file
        # cv.WarpPerspective(image, target, homography, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR | cv.CV_WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)        
        cv.PutText(target, '%s: perspective-transformed' % (os.path.basename(img_files[ii])), (100, 100), global_font, 0.0)
        cv.ShowImage('FixedImage', target)
        print '==================================================================='
        cv.WaitKey(0)
        ii += 1
    cv.DestroyWindow('OriginalImage')
    cv.DestroyWindow('CapturedImage')
    cv.DestroyWindow('FixedImage')
```

And the images:

Original:
[image: original image]

Captured Image:
[image: captured image]

Affine transformed original image:
[image: affine transformed original]

Now the inverse transform applied on the original image should solve the problem.